# How to display json data using for loop with flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I've tried to display JSON data within HTML using flask using `{% for bring in company %} ... {% endfor %}` loop with no success.However, I had applied JSON into the about.html page using direct application with the data/name as e.g:`{{races[0][name]}}` and it worked. I don't know what is the problem

I had even tried to find it and did not find any solution.

Python/Flask

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    data = []
    with open("data/races.json", "r") as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
    return render_template("about.html", page_title="About", races=data)

@app.route("/contact")
def contact():
    return render_template("contact.html", page_title="Contact")

@app.route("/careers")
def careers():
    return render_template("careers.html", page_title="Careers")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=os.environ.get("IP"),
            port=int(os.environ.get("PORT")),
            debug=True)
```

about.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<h2>{{ page_title}}</h2>
<p>
    StarCraft is a military science fiction media franchise, created by Chris Metzen and James Phinney and owned by Blizzard Entertainment. The series, set in the beginning of the 26th century, centers on a galactic struggle for dominance among four species—the
    adaptable and mobile Terrans, the ever-evolving insectoid Zerg, the powerfully enigmatic Protoss, and the "god-like" Xel'Naga creator race—in a distant part of the Milky Way galaxy known as the Koprulu Sector. The series debuted with the video game
    StarCraft in 1998. It has grown to include a number of other games as well as eight novelizations, two Amazing Stories articles, a board game, and other licensed merchandise such as collectable statues and toys.
</p>

{% for member in company %}
<div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>{{member.name}}</h3>
        <p>
            {{member.description}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="{{member.image_source}}"alt="Picture of {{ member.name }}"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

 {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

JSON

```
[
 {
     "name":"Terrans",
     "description":"The Terrans are a fictional future version of humanity in the StarCraft series. The Terrans are the most splintered of the StarCraft species, consisting of multiple factions and nations that not only fight the other races but each other as well. Consideredan adaptive and mobile species 'too stubborn or stupid to know when to give up' when faced with existential threat, the Terrans are noted in the lore of the series for their ability to quickly access and drain a planet's resources. The Terranshave been dedicated a full campaign in each real-time strategy video game installment to date, and are defined in-game by their specialization of units and tactics of defense, tanking, mobility, and overwhelming concentrated firepower; they are the only faction to not field any 'melee unit'. In the series' storyline, the Terrans are usually displayed as being caught in the conflict's crossfire between the Protoss and Zerg; they are forced to fight superior alien powers on two-frontwar at tremendous technological and evolutionary disadvantage, each determined to destroy the other, while also dealing with frequent internal strife, civil wars and revolutions.",
     "image_source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Tychus_Findlay_%28StarCraft%29.png"
 },
 {
     "name":"Zergs",
     "description":"The Zerg Swarm is a species of xenomorphic 'hyper-evolutionary' superorganisms; they are the overriding antagonists of the StarCraft series. Unlike the Protoss and the Terrans, the Zerg are not 'tool-makers', lacking technological inclination; instead, they 'force-evolve' genetic traits by directed mutation in order to match such technology. Operating as a hive mind-linked 'chain of command', the Zerg strive for 'genetic perfection' by assimilating the unique genetic adaptations of 'worthy' species into their own gene pool, creating numerous variations of specialised strains of Zerg gifted with unique adaptations. Despite being notoriously cunning and ruthlessly efficient, the majority of Zerg species have low intelligence; becoming mindless beasts if not connected to a 'hive-cluster' or a 'command entity'. As with the other two primary races, the Zerg are the subject of a full campaign in each of the series' real-time strategy video games. Zerg units are designed to be cost-efficient and fast to produce, encouraging players to overwhelm their opponents with a sheer numerical advantage. Since the release of StarCraft the Zerg have become a video gaming icon, described by PC Gamer UK as 'the best race in strategy history'. The term 'Zerg Rush' or 'zerging' has entered video gaming lexiconto describe sacrificing economic development in favour of using many low-cost fast/weak units to rush and overwhelm an enemy by attrition or sheer numbers. The tactic is infamous; most experienced real-time strategy players are familiar with the tactic in one form or another.",
     "image_source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Hydralisk_%28StarCraft%29.png"
 },
 {
     "name":"Protoss",
     "description":" The Protoss are a sapient humanoid species in the StarCraft series, originating from Aiur, a planet on the fringe of the galaxy. They consist of four societies, the conservative Khalai Protoss, the exiled Nerazim, the abandoned Purifiers and the sadisticTal'darim. The Protoss are depicted as a physically strong species with psionic abilities. The Protoss are the most technologically advanced race of the series and have been dedicated a full campaign in each instalment to date.",
     "image_source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/Zealot_%28StarCraft%29.png"
 } 
]
```

Once I had only one item (not three) within the JSON object it was working correctly, as I mentioned before, but I am almost sure that it is not the problem. Now, all the entire HTML within the loop does not appear on the screen when I run it to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send the data to the template as `races`, not `company`.

Comment: So it's a typo, basically?

Comment: @roganjosh yes. I placed the for loop using the oldest template name as I was reusing it from another code. So, instead of having ```{% for member in races %}```  into the about.html and displayed into the python ```races=data```. I was using ```{% for member in company %}```. That's why the probelm.

Answer (score 1):

try about.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<h2>{{ page_title}}</h2>
<p>
    StarCraft is a military science fiction media franchise, created by Chris Metzen and James Phinney and owned by Blizzard Entertainment. The series, set in the beginning of the 26th century, centers on a galactic struggle for dominance among four species—the
    adaptable and mobile Terrans, the ever-evolving insectoid Zerg, the powerfully enigmatic Protoss, and the "god-like" Xel'Naga creator race—in a distant part of the Milky Way galaxy known as the Koprulu Sector. The series debuted with the video game
    StarCraft in 1998. It has grown to include a number of other games as well as eight novelizations, two Amazing Stories articles, a board game, and other licensed merchandise such as collectable statues and toys.
</p>

{% for member in races %}
<div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>{{member.name}}</h3>
        <p>
            {{member.description}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="{{member.image_source}}"alt="Picture of {{ member.name }}"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

 {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```